# Is it okay to provide the definition of a constructor inside the header file that declares it?

Tags: c++, constructor, header

I am fairly new to C++, and I am sorry if this has been asked before but I did find a relevant answer.  I know that it is poor practice to define methods inside header files, unless they are class templates in which they has to be defined inside the header file.  How about for constructors?  For example, I define empty constructors in .h files like so:

```
bmd2FileException(const std::string & _description) throw() : bmd2Exception(_description) {}
```

I also have an overloaded constructor which has a non-empty definition:

```
bmd2FileException(const std::string & _description, const char *, long int) throw() {
  // do stuff
}
```

Do I need to include a seperate .cpp file for one or the other, or both constructors?

Thank you!

Comment: Who said it was poor practice?

Comment: I thought that if a method definition lived inside the header file, then if two different translation units included the header then each translation unit would have a copy of the same declaration/definition which would produce a name collision if the translation units were linked together.

Comment: No. That wouldn't be "poor practice", but an "error". As it happens, it is neither; member functions that are defined inline are implicitly `inline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define constructors in the header file, typically inside the class definition itself as you have been doing.

No, it isn't necessarily poor practice.  For example, it is probably silly to create a `cpp` file *just* to put the constructor definition somewhere other than the header, if the constructor is short and simple.

**Edit:** What you mention in your comments section about compiler errors about multiple definitions of the same function is true, but the situation where you define a class member method in the class definition is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your .h file is an interface file which means it just shows the methods you have but doesn't actually implement them. If you do want to do a .h and a .cpp file for one of your classes, you should probably implement your methods in your .cpp file instead of your .h file, as that is what the files were intended to be used for.

One reason you may not be able to implement functions in your constructors is that if two files need to include each other, you cannot have implementations in the headers.